# Update JSON Records in DynamoDB table using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have a JSON record which looks like:

```
 {'ip_address': data['src_ip'],
  'first_seen': data['timestamp'],
  'last_seen': data['timestamp']
                        }
```

The record gets stored in DynamoDB table with `ip_address` as the primary key.

When the same IP appears again, I want to update the last seen value. I created a function with below lines:

```
def update_db(json_result):
    ddb_data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_result), parse_float=Decimal)
    database = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
    table = database.Table('IPData')
    print("adding :", json_result)
    #db_add = table.put_item(Item = ddb_data)
    response = table.update_item(
                        Key = {
                            'ip_address': json_result['ip_address'] 
                        },
                        UpdateExpression="SET 'last_seen' = :s",
                        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
                                        ':s': json_result['last_seen']
                        },
                        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
                    )
    return response
```

This results into an error as:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"'\", near: \"SET 'last_seen\"",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
```

Not sure what is wrong in my syntax here. Can someone help me fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See the doc for [update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) and a `boto3` example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.03).

Your `UpdateExpression` should probably be (no single-quotes):

```
                        UpdateExpression="SET last_seen = :s",
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. There is a small problem. The first_seen field doesnt get added to the table with the above code. What should I do to make sure that all other fields are propagated as they are and just update the "last_seen" value.

Comment: No, that should work just fine; `table.update_item()` will leave the attributes unspecified as part of the update unchanged. Did you create the item with all the attributes in the first place? For example, `update_item()` on a non-existing key will create an item (with empty `first_seen`).

Comment: I am assuming that update_item should create everything which put_item would if the item doesnt already exists. If it does exist, then just update the last_seen time. That is my usecase. Can you help me with changes in the code that can achieve this.